# Compression when saving objects to disk - larger workspace object smaller size on disk?

Tags: r

I updated the code on my script to speed up the computation. In particular, I created some optional computation steps, which can be excluded by specification.

I saved my objects before and after the script change to disk via `save()`. The pre-changes workspace consists of 2 objects (`obj1` with *2682228* observations and *492* variables, making *8.9GB* when loaded into the workspace; `obj2` with *670557* observations and *422* variables, making *1.9GB* when loaded into the workspace). The post-changes workspace consists of the same 2 objects, but less complex (`obj1` with also *2682228* observations and *434* variables, making *7.8GB* when loaded into the workspace; `obj2` with also *670557* observations and *416* variables, making *1.9GB* when loaded into the workspace).

So the number of observations remains the same, but the datasets differ in number of variables. My logic would imply that the larger pre-changes workspace, when saved to disk, should also be larger than the smaller post-changes workspace. However, in fact it is the opposite. The pre-changes workspace measures *198MB* and the post-changes workspace measures *245MB*.

I find this extremely difficult to understand, because all the variables that are contained in the post-changes workspace are also contained in the pre-changes workspace. However, the pre-changes workspace also contains additional variables. Do you have any explanations for the fact that the compressed `.Rdata` file is smaller for an object that is larger in the workspace?

Comment: you may have gone from data with highly repetitive byte sequences (serialized format) to one with more unique byte sequences. You can try both saves at `compression_level=9` in `save()` to see if that makes a difference. Default is `-6` and, while good, it's still not going to do everything it can to fully compress the serialized objects.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks, I was also thinking about that. I am just wondering: if data.frame `a` is basically a subset data.frame `b`, can then the byte sequences of `a` be more complex than of `b`?

Comment: Aye. It cld have fewer repeating sequences that level 6 isn't going to make "smaller" due to the way DEFLATE works. I agree this particular instance seems "strange" but I've seen cases like it with other data files.